# I need to insert tab name in cell A1 of every tab with changing tab names

Tags: vba, excel

I need to open a worksheet with a fixed name and insert the name of each tab (which will change according to the current date) at the top of the sheet.

I modified some code from a previous answer and had the code working when it did not include the code to open the workbook. Now it flicks through the tabs but doesn't insert the name into `Cells(1, 1)` and I have no idea why. It also bugs at the end: `Run-time error 91`, which is less problematic but would be good to fix.

Any tips or advice much appreciated. Below is my current code:

```
Sub PSOPENTAB()
    ChDir "G:\directory"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\directory\filename.xls"
    Windows("filename.xls").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Call nametop
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub nametop()
    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        'exit if Activesheet is the last tab
        If .ActiveSheet.Index + 1 > .Worksheets.Count Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For i = .ActiveSheet.Index To .Worksheets.Count - 1
            .ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = .Worksheets(i).Name
             ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference your objects correctly.
Your problems are:

1. You use `Thisworkbook` in your `nametop` routine. So it will always work on the workbook containing the code.
2. You can change it to `ActiveWorkbook` but that may lead you to other problems in the future. [See this cool stuff to know more about why to avoid *Activeworkbook/Activesheet and the like*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Applying what's discussed there, try below code:

```
Sub PSOPENTAB()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\directory\filename.xls")
    nametop wb
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub nametop(wb As Workbook)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.Cells(1, 1) = ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Above code adds the name of the sheet in Cell A1 of every sheet.
Is this what you're trying?

Comment: Next i should be `Next ws`

Comment: Hello! I changed it to Sub PSOPENTAB()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("G:\directory\filename.xls").Worksheets(1)
    nametop wb
End Sub

Sub nametop(wb As Workbook)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With wb
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Cells(1, 1) = ws.Name
        Next i
    End With
End Sub                to get it to start on the first tab and to get rid of a couple of errors it was pulling, but now I'm getting the same issue (i.e. it's looping, I think, but not filling in the name in the cell)

Comment: Hi Chris - this returns a Invalid Next control variable reference, so I don't think it can be correct.

Comment: @RachelDear Can you illustrate how you're expected result looks like?

Comment: The idea above (adding the name of the sheet in Cell A1 of every sheet) is perfect, it's just not working. I'm going to try the code on a different spreadsheet in case it's a formatting issue.

Comment: @L42 I'm getting a type mismatch error here on Set wb = Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\directory\filename.xls"

Comment: @L42, we have lift-off!! Superb. Many thanks for all your assistance.